# Simple C++ write-to-file not working within Mac OS X App - why? (and why me?)

Tags: c++, macos, fileoutputstream

The code is simple enough:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::ofstream theStream;
    theStream.open("trash.txt");
    theStream << "some words" << std::endl;
    theStream.close();
}
```

If I run it from the command line then I get the expected file in the same directory.  If a package the contents of the executable within a MacOS .app, then no file is written anywhere.  (Or perhaps it is just promptly erased?)

Here's the simple script I'm using to place the executable into the .app.  Perhaps that is where I'm going wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash

appName=MyApp
if [ $1 ] 
then 
    appName=$1
else 
    echo "usage: convertToApp executableFile"
    exit
fi

if [ -e "$appName" ] 
then
    mkdir $appName.app
    mkdir $appName.app/Contents
    mkdir $appName.app/Contents/MacOS
    mkdir $appName.app/Contents/Resources
    cp $appName $appName.app/Contents/MacOS/$appName
    echo -n 'APPL????' > $appName.app/Contents/PkgInfo
else
    echo "specified file does not exist"
fi
```

Any idea why I can't see the file I want to see?

Comment: Where do you expect the file to appear? Why do you expect it to appear there?

Comment: you need to consider what the current working directory of the application is when it is run as an application, instead of as a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of "trash.txt", try to use the full path or change the current working directory.

Comment: It's either this, or a permissions problem. I don't see any error checking. Check: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/fail/

Comment: @Aaron: He's using a relative path, so that's most likely why the write succeeds at the command line but fails when he executes the .app--applications don't usually have write access to their own bundles, but the command line usually drops you off somewhere in your home folder, where you have write access. (Well, that's my interpretation, anyway.)